# Failing to start java program ClassNotFound exception received

Tags: java, jsoup

Trying to start java program on linux but it fails to locate JSoup jar file. I have checked other questions and found on how to add libraries while compiling and while trying to run it but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly because it still fails to load the library....

I enter the following commands:

```
root@vps5441:/var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader# javac -cp /var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader/jsoup-1.8.1.jar:/var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. TimetableLoader.java                
root@vps5441:/var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader# java -cp /var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader/jsoup-1.8.1.jar:/var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. -classpath /var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader/ TimetableLoader
```

And I get the following error when the program tries to access the JSoup library.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at TimetableLoader.main(TimetableLoader.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume jsoup-1.8.1.jar is in the current directory?

You don't generally need both `-classpath` and `-cp`.  It's probably ignoring the values given by `-cp` as a result.

Put your own classes ahead of the 3rd-party ones.

You're already in /var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader so keep it simple:-

```
root@vps5441:/var/www/var/www/TimetableLoader# java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar  TimetableLoader
```

*(Best to get out of the habit of running things as "root" unless you have a genuine need, just sayin')*